# I'm trying to generate rating stars for products, rating value(0 to 5) is already served as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
class PostBodyRatingStars extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    var rating = this.props.rating

    function createMappingArray(rating) {
      var arr = []
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (rating >= 1) {
          arr.push('1')
          rating = rating--
        } else if (rating == 0.5) {
          arr.push('0.5')
        } else arr.push('0')
      }
      return arr
    }

    function createStars(arr) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        switch (arr[i]) {
          case '0':
            return <StarBorder />
          case '0.5':
            return <StarHalf />
          case '1':
            return <Star />
        }
      }
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {arr.map(n => {
          createStars(n)
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The idea here is to create an array from the rating variable, that will have 5 elements: 0, 0.5 or 1 with the createMappingArray function.

Then map over that array, with the createStars function as mapping parameter and generate the 5 stars, full half or empty. The star components are material-ui icons.

> ReferenceError: arr is not defined

I am pretty sure there isn't just a single issue here, i'm not big into Vanilla JS.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: At a quick glance var arr = [] is inside your createMappingArray - try putting it below var rating.

Comment: Yes that did the trick now it compiles. Thank you. I now added console.log(createStars(['0', '0', '0.5', '1', '1'])) just before the return, and i changed createStars so that it returns "a" "b" or "c", but i get 5 "a", instead of gettinng "a" "a" "b" "c" "c"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like youre calling createMappingArray anywhere.

What is the purpose of createStars? To take a value and return a star, or to take an array of values and return an array of stars? Right now it takes an array, but returns as soon as it matches the first element to its star.

I think maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
class PostBodyRatingStars extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    var rating = this.props.rating

    function createMappingArray(rating) {
      var arr = []
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (rating >= 1) {
          arr.push('1')
          rating = rating--
        } else if (rating == 0.5) {
          arr.push('0.5')
        } else arr.push('0')
      }
      return arr
    }

    function pickStar(star) {
        switch (star) {
          case '0':
            return <StarBorder />
          case '0.5':
            return <StarHalf />
          case '1':
            return <Star />
        }
      }
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {createMappingArray(rating).map(n => {
          pickStar(n)
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I think your confusion may come from the fact that you're declaring functions with parameter names that are the same as other variables (like rating). This doesn't execute the function, you have to do that separately and give it the parameter value you want it to use.

Comment: I have no clue why your code doesn't compile, the syntax seems good to me. Terminal gives: Syntax Error: Unexpected token (41:6) about the div tag in the return()

Comment: It simply doesn't let me have a return() statement

Comment: Nevermind it compiles now, but i still get no stars:(